# i don't know why this code be warning core dump

Tags: c, coredump

I'm trying run a IPC though shared memory code and be warning Core dump
please look at the code

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)

    key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);

    int shmid = shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);

    char *str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);

    printf("Write Data : ");
    scanf("%s",&str);


    printf("Data written in memory: %s\n",str);
    
    shmdt(str);

    return 0;

}
```

so how can i fix it?

this is the warnning when i run it in commandline ubuntu
[1]   Segmentation fault (core dumped) ./write

Comment: This is not a warning but an error. It instantly kills your program. You are accessing memory not regarded as your programs.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&str);` ==> `scanf("%s", str);`

Comment: `str` is already a pointer, not need for the `&` here `scanf("%s",&str);`. You should check to be sure `str` is not `NULL` before using it as well as checking for potential errors from other function return values.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Whenever this happens, you should run your program in a debugger. It should tell you where the segfault happened. Then you can inspect all involved variables at that place.

Comment: The compiler should warn you about the wrong pointer type at `scanf`.